# Printing a capture of Dialog/Popup only

Tags: android, printing, screen-capture

So in my app I want to get a popup dialog to be printed once a certain button is clicked. (assuming that the phone is connected to the printer via Wifi/bluetooth)

[image: Dialog popup]

How can I do it? If I do it by first taking screenshot then there would be useless background coming back as well. I only want the dialog (no other view).

Comment: Can you share the code you're using for taking the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I guess u need a full screen dialog(It will cover up the whole screen without showing the background).

1. Create a full screen layout
2. Create dialog using fullscreen theme `Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)`